# Silent notifications only received when phone is open

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, healthkit

So I am having an issue that I thought you guys might be able to help out with. I have an iOS app built by a third party vendor. I have an api that i built myself to work along side the app to consume data from the healthkit database on the device. The flow is this:

User downloads, installs and authorizes app to access healthkit data.
User opens app and logs in via the api. 
App sends healthkit data back to api with user credentials so I can store data sent and attribute it to a user.

All works great. Now the part that isn't working so great. We're using FCM to send silent notifications with an attribute in the data object of

`{ task: syncnow }`

when this silent notification is received, it checks if the task is syncnow and if so, it sends the healthkit data to our servers so the users don't have to remember to manually sync it everyday. The problem is that it only seems to be received when the phone is awake and not locked. The app seems to wake fine if the phone is actively being used, but if the phone is locked and the screen is off, nothing comes through. I've tried adding a sound to the aps object on the JSON, I have

`content_available: true`

in the aps object as well. By all accounts, it should be working as intended, but it isn't. FCM always returns successful sends to all in the array of users in the to object as well.

my JSON structure looks like this:

`{to: [array_of_fcm_tokens], data:{task: syncnow}, aps: {content_available: true, sound: ''}}`

I've also tried moving the content_available to the top level of the object instead of in the aps object, I've tried different variations of content_available, content-available and different value types(string, int, bool). Nothing seems to work. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the possibilities to fix

1) Add "content-available" = 1 in your payload

2) Receive it via

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler:@escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { 
}
```

3)Make sure your apps background refresh is on in device settings

4)Make sure you have added background mode for remote notifications in app

5)Restart the device

Comment: all seems to be in perfect working order. I have made sure all of this is correct and it does appear to be, but the phone is still not receiving silent notifications when it is locked. I have tried just about everything and I can not get this to be received. unlocked is fine, even if the app is closed. Here is my current payload that works fine when the phone is open:



```[to] => '',    
[data] => Array
        (
            [task] => syncnow
            [next_sync] => 9:00 AM
        )

    [content_available] => 1```

Comment: change the content_available to content-available